# Run Ant task on SVN/GIT commit in Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, svn, ant, intellij-idea

How can I configure Intellij IDEA to execute my Ant
task each time I commit changes to SVN/git repository?

Comment: On your site I'l try to use (implement) Continuous integration process - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration. The TeamCity server (has native integration with IDEA), for example, let you more opportunities and features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature out of the box, but this functionality can be added via custom plug-in (though, there is no such plug-in yet, AFAIK).

You can also [vote for the existing feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5755).